# Combining big set of layers with npm+webpack and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have a really big set of layers in OpenLayers 5.
I wonder how to split large source files into smaller sets and combine it via webpack.

style.js file about 30 items e.g.:

`var s_al_timeout = function(feature, resolution) {
    var fGet = parseFloat(feature.get('last_read_timeout'));
    ...
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                   ...
            })
        })];
  }`,

vector source.js file about 30 items e.g.:

`var vS_alarm_timeout = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function(extent) {
        $.ajax('/wfs_ant',{
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                ...
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
                },
            }).done(ldFe_alarm_timeout);
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });
var ldFe_alarm_timeout = function(response) {
    formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
    fT_alarm_timeout = formatWFS.readFeatures(response);
    vS_alarm_timeout.addFeatures(fT_alarm_timeout);
  };
function refresh_alarm_timeout(){
    vS_alarm_timeout.clear(true);
    vS_alarm_timeout.addFeatures(fT_alarm_timeout);
}`

**And how to use $.ajax loader in webpack?**
(Loading jquery, good tutorial for ajax:
https://alexomara.com/blog/webpack-and-jquery-include-only-the-parts-you-need/)

Popup file also many lines code. 
Basic code file (combine map and layers with source vector and style file).

I try with npm and webpack but I don't know how to import these smaller files...
I seek tips or examples.

Trying split code into: ./script/source.js + ./script/style.js

in main.js:

```
require ('./scripts/source');    
require ('./scripts/style');
```

and in webpack.config.js add: `entry: ['./main.js', './scripts/source.js', './scripts/style.js']`

But no luck `Uncaught ReferenceError: vS_alarm_timeout is not defined` 
and `vS_alarm_timeout` is name of the source layer in main.js.

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is communication between pieces of code via import and export.
It's so simple and work very good.

### Example:

main.js

```
import {v_vector_layer1} from './source/wfs/vector_layer1';
```

vector_layer1.js

```
export var v_vector_layer1;
```

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.